# Cannot override a renderer in Moodle

Tags: php, moodle

I have tried following the [Moodle documentation](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Overriding_a_renderer) on how to override a renderer, but it does not work for some reason. Here is what I have done:

1. Created a folder called overridetest in `/theme/` directory.
2. Created a file called `config.php` in `/theme/` directory:

```
<?php

    $THEME->name = 'overridetest';
    $THEME->parents = array('standard', 'base');
    
    $THEME->rendererfactory = 'theme_overriden_renderer_factory';
    
    $THEME->sheets = Array('overridetest');
```

3. Created a `renderers.php` file in `/theme/` directory:

```
<?php

    class theme_overridetest_core_renderer extends core_renderer
    {
        public function heading($text, $level = 2, $classes = 'main', $id = null)
        {
            $content = html_writer::start_tag('div', array('class' => 'headingcontainer'));
            $content .= html_writer::empty_tag('img', array('src' => $this->pix_url('headingpic', 'theme'), 'alt' => '', 'class' => 'headingimage'));
            $content .= parent::heading($text, $level, $classes, $id);
            $content .= html_writer::end_tag('div');
            
            return $content;
        }
    }
```

4. Created the directory `/theme/overridetest/pix/` and included an image `headingpic.png`.
5. Created a directory `/theme/overridetest/style/` and included a file called `overridetest.css`:

```
.headingcontainer .headingimage
{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1em;
}

.headingcontainer h2,

.headingcontainer h3,

.headingcontainer h4,

.headingcontainer h5,

.headingcontainer h6
{
    text-align: left;
}
```

However, this does not seem to work. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably has to do with the version of Moodle you are using. The method you showed here is working for older Moodle versions (lower than 2.8, according to the documentation).

For newer versions, you have to override renderers in your plugins. In your case, you could override it in your own theme, if you're rolling a custom one.

Let's say that you have created your own theme called `mycustomtheme` (the easiest is to create a **Boost child theme** https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Creating_a_theme_based_on_boost).

You could override the heading function by doing the following :

- install your `mycustomtheme` plugin (by visiting the home page when logged in as an administrator)
- register `mycustomtheme` as the main theme in *Site Administration > Appearance > Themes > Theme selector*
- turn on the Theme Editor Mode (in *Site Administration > Appearance > Themes > Theme settings*)
- create a file named `core_renderer.php` in `/theme/mycustomtheme/classes/output/`

```php
<?php

namespace theme_mycustomtheme\output;

use html_writer;

defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die;

class core_renderer extends \core_renderer {
    public function heading($text, $level = 2, $classes = 'main', $id = null) {
        $content = html_writer::start_tag('div', array('class' => 'headingcontainer'));
        $content .= html_writer::empty_tag('img', array(
                    'src' => $this->image_url('headingpic', 'theme'), 
                    'alt' => '', 'class' => 'headingimage'));
        $content .= parent::heading($text, $level, $classes, $id);
        $content .= html_writer::end_tag('div');
        return $content;
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note: It is crucial to use the namespace according to moodle convention. theme_YOUR_THEME_NAME\output. YOUR_THEME_NAME must be identical to the name of your theme folder, most likely for autoloading reasons.

If you use namespace `theme_my_creative_theme_name\output` your theme folder must be named `my_creative_theme_name`.